# How do I merge 2 dataframes based on either/or comparison?

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have:

```
edu_data = [['school', 1, 2], ['college', 3, 4], ['grad-school', 5, 6]] 
edu = pd.DataFrame(edu_data, columns = ['Education', 'StudentID1', 'StudentID2']) 
print(edu)
     Education  StudentID1  StudentID2
0       school         1         2
1      college         3         4
2  grad-school         5         6
```

And then I have another table with people's student ids:

```
data = [['tom', 3], ['nick', 5], ['juli', 6], ['jack', 10]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'StudentID']) 
print(df)
   Name  StudentID
0   tom        3
1  nick        5
2  juli        6
3  jack       10
```

How would I get a table where I would match df['StudentID'] against either  edu["StudentID1"] or edu["StudentID2"]. If df['StudentID'] equals either  then I would like to append edu["Education"] to df.

So I would expect my output to be:

```
   Name  StudentID  Education
0   tom        3     college
1  nick        5     grad-school
2  juli        6     grad-school
3  jack       10     NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using map, similar to my answer earlier today

```
mapper = edu.set_index('StudentID1')['Education'].to_dict()
mapper.update(edu.set_index('StudentID2')['Education'].to_dict())

df['Education'] = df['StudentID'].map(mapper)


    Name    StudentID   Education
0   tom     3           college
1   nick    5           grad-school
2   juli    6           grad-school
3   jack    10          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
mapper=edu.melt(id_vars='Education',var_name = 'StudentID',value_name='ID').set_index('ID')
df['Education']=df['StudentID'].map(mapper['Education'])
print(df)

   Name  StudentID    Education
0   tom          3      college
1  nick          5  grad-school
2  juli          6  grad-school
3  jack         10          NaN
```

**Detail:**

```
print(mapper)

         Education   StudentID
ID                         
1           school  StudentID1
3          college  StudentID1
5      grad-school  StudentID1
2           school  StudentID2
4          college  StudentID2
6      grad-school  StudentID2
```

---

Also you can use [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) + [`Series.combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html):

```
eduID1=edu.set_index('StudentID1')
eduID2=edu.set_index('StudentID2')
df['Education']=df['StudentID'].map(eduID1['Education']).combine_first(df['StudentID'].map(eduID2['Education']))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Name  StudentID    Education
0   tom          3      college
1  nick          5  grad-school
2  juli          6  grad-school
3  jack         10          NaN
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `map`

```
s = edu.set_index('Education').stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

df['Education'] = df.StudentID.map(pd.Series(s.index, s.values))
```

---

```
   Name  StudentID    Education
0   tom          3      college
1  nick          5  grad-school
2  juli          6  grad-school
3  jack         10          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution with `melt` and `merge`:

```
(df.merge(edu.melt(id_vars='Education', 
                  value_name='StudentID'),
         on='StudentID',
         how='left')     
      .drop_duplicates(['Name','StudentID'])    # this is for when both StudentID match, we choose the first
     .drop('variable', axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
   Name  StudentID    Education
0   tom          3      college
1  nick          5  grad-school
2  juli          6  grad-school
3  jack         10          NaN
```